# How to execute 2 scripts on a server via ssh by chaining them and within only a single connection?

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, scripting

I have these 2 commands that I send to my server:

```
- cat ./script1.sh var1 var2 | ssh my_user@my_server.com
- cat ./script2.sh var3 var4 | ssh my_user@my_server.com
```

This is a part of Gitlab CI, but this doesn't matter.

Is there any way to merge these 2 lines -- execute script1.sh and then script2.sh on a server? So that they'll execute within a *single* ssh connection.

Preferably without having to create an additional 3rd script that'll call those 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
( echo "set var1 var2"; cat ./script1.sh; echo "set var3 var4"; cat ./script2.sh ) | ssh my_user@my_server.com
```

Comment: `var`s are used -- they're command line arguments

Comment: The command being "cat", they will only be used if they are filenames, in which case their content will be concatenated to that of the script and the whole sent to myserver.com.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: I know.  Can you transfer the scripts to myserver.com?

Comment: no, they have to be a part of my project, in the repo

Comment: Do you understand what happens when you (or your project) executes  "cat /script1.sh var1 var2 " ?  You can try it yourself.

Comment: Even if these scripts are part of your project, you could very easily  "scp ./script1.sh  my_user@my_server.com:/tmp/".

Comment: But I believe I did find a solution.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Damn, look at my reputation now!

Comment: sorryyyyy! now it's 651!!!

Comment: :))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: Speaking of the devil :-(

Comment: you're devil again

Comment: It feels good  ]:->⇝